# Is it possible to download Indexdata from Yahoofinance with the tq_get function and have the weekend dates filled?

Tags: r, yahoo-finance

I'm currently trying to write a shiny app, that can plot two things:

- the returns of a cryptoportfolio
- the returns of the DAX ("^GDAXI" on Yahoo finance)

The first part is no problem. The problem is, that the DAX-data only consists of 5 values/week, while the cryptodata consists of 7 values per week.
So although i can calculate the returns of the DAX, i cant plot it in a chart together with the returns of the cryptoportfolio, because i get fewer values for the same time period.
So my question is the following: Is it possible, to download the data for the DAX, and have the values for the weekends filled? NAs would be absolutely fine - then i could fill them with na.locf - but unfortunately i only get the data completely without the weekend-days.
The data looks like this - as you can see, the weekend-days are completely missing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMnDM.png)

Until now, i've calculated the returns like this:

```
library(tidyquant)


dax = tq_get("^GDAXI",
             from="2020-01-01",
             to=,"2021-01-01",
             get="stock.prices",)

dax_daily_returns=dax%>%
  tq_transmute(select=adjusted,
               mutate_fun=periodReturn,
               period="daily",
               col_rename="ret")
dax_daily_returns=dax%>%
  tq_transmute(select=adjusted,
               mutate_fun=periodReturn,
               period="daily",
               col_rename="ret")

dax_cum_returns=dax_daily_returns%>%
  mutate(cr=cumprod(1+dax_daily_returns$ret))

dax_cum_returns=as.data.frame(dax_cum_returns)
dax_cum_returns[,1]=as.Date(dax_cum_returns[,1])
dax_returns_cum=xts(dax_cum_returns[,3], order.by=as.Date(dax_cum_returns[,1]))
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Phil that's exactly what they want to do: *"NAs would be absolutely fine - then i could fill them with na.locf"*

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example of the data as it stands before where you need help.

Comment: @phil I added a picture

Comment: I'm not sure what type of object the `tq_get` function returns or what package it's from, but it should be easy enough to add the missing dates with `NA` values using `tidyr::complete`, or `merge` or `match` from base, or a `dplyr` or `data.table` join. If you share a small reproducible example we can help you much more quickly. Include `library()` statements for necessary packages and either use `dput()` to share a copy/pasteable version of a small subset of data (just 1 or 2 weeks should be plenty), or share runnable code to produce such data.

Comment: @Silura Please copy and paste the output of `dput(head(mydataframe))` instead of an image of data. We are not going to type these out.

Comment: added a runnable code